# Behaviour of virtual inheritance in this case

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I wrote this program with virtual inheritance and I have a few questions.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class B1
{
 public:
  B1()
  {
    cout << "In B1 constructor\n";
  }
};

class V1 : public B1
{
 public:
  V1()
  {
    cout << "In V1 constructor\n";
  }
};

class D1 : virtual public V1
{
 public:
  D1()
  {
    cout << "In D1 constructor\n";
  }
};

class B2
{
 public:
  B2()
  {
    cout << "In B2 constructor\n";
  }
};

class B3 {
 public:
  B3()
  {
    cout << "In B3 constructor\n";
  }
};

class V2 : public B1, public B2
{
 public:
  V2()
  {
    cout << "In V2 constructor\n";
  }
};

class D2 : public B3, virtual public V2
{
 public:
  D2()
  {
    cout << "In D2 constructor\n";
  }
};

class X : public D1, virtual public D2
{
 public:
  X()
  {
    cout << "In X constructor\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  X x;
  return 0;
}
```

Output of the program:

```
In B1 constructor
In V1 constructor
In B1 constructor
In B2 constructor
In V2 constructor
In B3 constructor
In D2 constructor
In D1 constructor
In X constructor
```

I expected an output like this:

```
In B1 constructor
In B2 constructor
In V2 constructor
In B2 constructor
In D2 constructor
In B1 constructor
In V1 constructor
In D1 constructor
In X constructor
```

on the basis that an object of a virtual base class is constructed first and then the other base class object. Can Someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Hug? You want one `B2` subobject to be constructed twice???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact quote from the standard is 12.6.2p10:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), **virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes**, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.

I believe the key is the *depth-first left to right* in the bolded text. The `V1` class is a virtual base of `X` that is to the *left* of `V2`, even if it is *deeper* in the hierarchy.

The hierarchy graph in your case is like:

```
            X
          /   \\
        D1     D2
        ||    / \\
        V1  B3   V2
        |       /  \
        B1    B1*   B2
```

Where single lines identify plain inheritance, and double lines are virtual inheritance. Note that there are two instances of `B1` in your complete object `X`. Now if you perform a *depth-first left-to-right* search you will walk the nodes in the following order:

```
[ B1, V1, D1, B3, B1*, B2, V2, D2, X ]
```

And the virtual bases are `V1`, `V2`, `D2`, which is the order in which they will be constructed. `V1` requires the construction of `B1`. `V2` requires the construction of `B1*` and `B2`, `D2` requires `B3`, so the order should be:

```
[ B1, V1, B1*, B2, V2, B3, D2, D1, X ]
```

Where `B1` construction is triggered by `V1`, `B1*` and `B2` must be ordered before `V2`, `B3` is triggered as a dependency of `D2`. At this point all of the virtual bases are built and the non-virtual bases start to be constructed. The only non-virtual base of `X` that has not been initialized due to the dependencies of the virtual bases is `D1`.

If the diamond was closed (say that `V1` and `V2` inherited virtually from `B1`, then there would be only one instance of `B1` and it would be the first subobject to be constructed.

Comment: virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes.... Seems a little tricky for me to understand  :(

Comment: What if you take a mirror image of the diagram you might have drawn and say now `V2` is to left of `V1` with `B2` and `B3` also appearing on left side of diagram as its a diamond structure

Comment: The standard says *where "left-to-right" is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-speficier-list*. "Left-to-right" is well defined in this case.

Comment: What if the branch D2 and D1 are interchanged as its a diamond shape . is there any specific reason for them to be as such ?

Comment: class X : public D1, virtual public D2 you mean because of this statement ? But isnt then defining D2 as virtual here means it should be constructed first ?

Comment: I guess its a wonderful explaination by you . Thanks for all your effort

Comment: @Ritesh: Defining `D2` as virtual there means that it will be initialized before any non-virtual bases of `X`, for example `D1`, but for the set of virtual bases the order is defined by the tree transversal, where *left* is declared before in the *base-class-specifier*, and deep is further away in the inheritance hierarchy from the root `X`.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination :)

Answer (score 0):

C++ always constructs the “first” or “most base” class first. It then walks through the inheritance tree in order and constructs each successive derived class.

Comment: This has a diamond structure . Can you let me know Which path was given a prefernce and on What basis ?

Comment: @Ritesh: To be clear, there is no *diamond* in that hierarchy. There are multiple `B1` bases.